# php html display hierarchical data

Tags: php, html, hierarchical

I have an array ($title, $depth)

```
$title($depth)
////////////////////////////////////
ELECTRONICS(0)
    TELEVISIONS(1)
        TUBE(2)
        LCD(2)
        PLASMA(2)
    PORTABLE ELECTRONICS(1)
        MP3 PLAYERS(2)
            FLASH(3)
        CD PLAYERS(2)
        2 WAY RADIOS(2)
//////////////////////
```

How could I display this structure with `<ul><li>`

Comment: What is your question exactly? What aspect of doing this are you stuck with?

Comment: What does your actual array look like, can you show us a `print_r` or `var_dump` of it?

Comment: i wanna create vertical menu with this

Comment: But what your data looks like?

Comment: What is your question exactly? What aspect of doing this are you stuck with?

Answer (score 0):

The basics of it...keep track of the depth, and print out `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags to nudge the depth toward the current depth.  Keep in mind that HTML does not require `</li>` tags, and it makes life easier.  You can just print out a `<li>` before each item, and let the elements close themselves as needed.

Now, as for the specifics of going over your list, it depends on the structure (which, at the time of this edit, you haven't cared to share).  There are two sensible ways i can think of to structure such a list, though.

```
$depth = -1;
// May be foreach($arr as $title => $itemDepth), depending on the structure
foreach ($arr as $item)
{
    // if you did the 'other' foreach, get rid of this
    list($title, $itemDepth) = $item;

    // Note, this only works decently if the depth increases by
    // at most one level each time.  The code won't work if you
    // suddenly jump from 1 to 5 (the intervening <li>s won't be
    // generated), so there's no sense in pretending to cover that
    // case with a `while` or `str_repeat`.
    if ($depth < $itemDepth)
        echo '<ul>';
    elseif ($depth > $itemDepth)
        echo str_repeat('</ul>', $depth - $itemDepth);

    echo '<li>', htmlentities($title);
    $depth = $itemDepth;
}

echo str_repeat('</ul>', $depth + 1);
```

This won't generate valid XHTML.  But most people shouldn't be using XHTML anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function like this.

```
$data = array(
    'electronics' => array(
        'televisions' => array(
            'tube',
            'lcd',
            'plasma',
        ),
        'portable electronics' => array(
            'MP3 players' => array(
                'flash',
            ),
            'CD players',
            '2 way radios',
        ),
    ),
);

function build_ul($contents){
    $list = "<ul>\n";

    foreach($contents as $index => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $item = "$index\n" . build_ul($value);
        } else {
            $item = $value;
        }
       $list .= "\t<li>$item</li>\n";
    }

    $list .= "</ul>\n";

    return $list;
}


print build_ul($data);
```

You'll have to modify the function in order to add the numbers showing totals for the category.

Note that because PHP is not optimized for handling recursive functions like some other languages (e.g. Lisp), you may run into performance problems if you have large amounts of data.  On the other hand, if you've got a hierarchical structure deeper than three or maybe four levels, you're going to start running to problems anyway because it's hard to display that much hierarchy sensibly in a single web page.